# vscode: How to see entire cell output in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

**Context:** I'm running a Jupyter notebook in vscode. I have a dataframe with 100 columns and want to print all columns.

**Problem:** notebooks in vscode has a built-in limit on the maximum output length. I've already changed the notebook "text line limit" to 100, and nothing changed. I also restarted vscode, and rerun the notebook.

**How to see the entire output?**

[image]

[image]

Comment: convert it to a string and print that, maybe line by line, write a helper function for this, what if the string rep of a data frame limits the output, write a helper to convert a data frame to individual elements and print these, maybe for the really big output write it to a file and view it in VSC tab

Comment: Did you try `list(runs_df.columns)` or `runs_df.columns.tolist()`?

Comment: @Wayne doing `runs_df.columns.tolist()` works well!

Answer (score 0):

`runs_df.columns.tolist()` solves the problem